# Convert HttpPostedFileBase to byte[]

Tags: arrays, image, asp.net-mvc-3

In my MVC application, I am using following code to upload a file.

**MODEL**

```
 public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
```

**VIEW**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File, new { type = "file" })
```

Everything working fine .. But I am trying to convert the result fiel to byte[] .How can i  do this

**CONTROLLER**

```
 public ActionResult ManagePhotos(ManagePhotos model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            byte[] image = model.File; //Its not working .How can convert this to byte array
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 277, accepted):

As Darin says, you can read from the input stream - but I'd avoid relying on all the data being available in a single go. If you're using .NET 4 this is simple:

```
MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream();
model.File.InputStream.CopyTo(target);
byte[] data = target.ToArray();
```

It's easy enough to write the equivalent of `CopyTo` in .NET 3.5 if you want. The important part is that you read from [`HttpPostedFileBase.InputStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase.inputstream.aspx).

For efficient purposes you *could* check whether the stream returned is already a `MemoryStream`:

```
byte[] data;
using (Stream inputStream = model.File.InputStream)
{
    MemoryStream memoryStream = inputStream as MemoryStream;
    if (memoryStream == null)
    {
        memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        inputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
    }
    data = memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: The first example didn't work for me in .NET4 (didn't try the other one) - It didn't work when I tried it with a .png or .jpg, however it did work when I used a .txt file. Any idea why :)

Comment: @VoodooChild: Presumably *something* in what you're doing is treating the data as text. I'd need to see more code to know what though. I suggest you ask another question giving your full scenario.

Comment: ok this worked for me, just to give some context - Thanks!
`            Image img = Image.FromStream(file.InputStream);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            model.SiteLogo = ms.ToArray();`

Comment: Jon's answer didn't work for me, the copied to memoryStream was always empty. Voodoo's answer worked for me, I guess it should be stated that this solution is only for text, not images?

Comment: @Justin: No, absolutely not. What part of the code do you think is text-related? I suspect something else is going on in your situation, but it's hard to tell from just the description you've given. Perhaps you've already read from the stream, for example? I *think* I remember seeing that `Image.FromStream` will rewind a `MemoryStream` which is at the end, though I could be wrong. That would certainly explain it.

Comment: I was finding that the inputstream position was at the end of the stream, so I had to add the line `model.File.InputStream.Position = 0;` before Jon's code to make it work

Comment: @Manish: I suspect you'd already used it earlier in the code. It would be unusual for it to be positioned at the end before you'd done anything.

Comment: When I pass resulted byte[] to other function for some reason it become empty. I think this is related to MemoryStream garbage collection. So need to find other way to copy.

Comment: @vk5880: It's not clear what you mean by "become empty" but an array *cannot* change size after it is created. Additionally, `MemoryStream` does *not* change the content of the byte array on disposal or finalization. I suggest you ask a new question demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet: My fault. If you have read empty array of bytes, check you haven't read HttpPostedFileBase.InputStream before. You can't read HttpPostedFileBase.InputStream twice, you need to seek to start.

Comment: In the first code snippet: Is it OK to _not_ wrap the `target` variable inside a `using` statement here?

Comment: @UweKeim: Well yes, we've already got a using statement (not directive, btw) for `inputStream`, and both will refer to the same object. Why would you want to dispose of it twice?

Comment: Sorry, I've written the wrong variable. I meant `target`.

Answer (score 31):

You can read it from the input stream:

```
public ActionResult ManagePhotos(ManagePhotos model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        byte[] image = new byte[model.File.ContentLength];
        model.File.InputStream.Read(image, 0, image.Length); 

        // TODO: Do something with the byte array here
    }
    ...
}
```

And if you intend to directly save the file to the disk you could use the `model.File.SaveAs` method. You might find the [following blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx) useful.

Comment: Is the InputStream for an HttpPostedFileBase *guaranteed* to return all its data in a single call to Read? It's best to avoid that where possible.

Comment: I found this only worked if I reset the position in the image stream between the two lines:

byte[] image = new byte[file.ContentLength];
file.InputStream.Position = 0;

ile.InputStream.Read(image, 0, image.Length);

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] file = new byte[excelFile.ContentLength];
excelFile.InputStream.Read(file, 0, file.Length);

//Create memory stream object from your bytes
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(file);

// Set WorkbookPart , Sheet
using (var myDoc = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.SpreadsheetDocument.Open(ms, true))
```