# How do I retrieve image properly using ParseFile?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, parse-platform

I'm using the following code to save an image

```
ParseFile file = null;

if (ProfileImage != null && ProfileImage.ContentLength > 0 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ProfileImage.FileName))
{
    byte[] fileBytes = new byte[ProfileImage.ContentLength];
    file = new ParseFile(ProfileImage.FileName, fileBytes);
    await file.SaveAsync();

var player = new ParseObject("Player");
if(file != null)
{
    player["ProfilePic"] = file;
}

await player.SaveAsync();
}
```

I'm trying to retrieve the image so I can display using the following code

```
ParseObject player = Task.Run(() =>
    ParseObject.GetQuery("Player").WhereEqualTo("objectId", id).FirstOrDefaultAsync()).Result;

    ParseFile profileImage = null;
    string profileImageUrl = "";
    if (player.ContainsKey("ProfilePic"))
            {
                profileImage = player.Get<ParseFile>("ProfilePic");
                profileImageUrl = profileImage.Url.AbsoluteUri;
            }
```

profileImageUrl have a correct url such as http://files.parsetfss.com/c8db8833-b04b-4877-8040-b70df1ec216c/tfss-11c442f3-6146-4316-a6c0-7c9a063d897e-Koala.jpg

However, the image is always broken.  I'm trying to display the image using html  tag and the image is always broken.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example image contains 762Kb of zero-bytes. I can't really see in your save method that you actually put content in the array either.

```
byte[] fileBytes = new byte[ProfileImage.ContentLength];
file = new ParseFile(ProfileImage.FileName, fileBytes);
await file.SaveAsync();
```

The code above creates an empty array of x bytes long and then you save it. You should put the picture bytes in there somehow. I can't tell from your code what type the ProfileImage object is, but i suppose you can get the content bytes from that object.

Comment: ProfileImage is HttpPostedFileBase.  Its from an html <input type="file"> that is submitted to a form

Comment: Look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852102/convert-httppostedfilebase-to-byte for more information then. This thread gives an example to get the bytes from the posted file.