# Cannot modify ModelState using SetModelValue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I'm working on a MVC/EF Web Application. In one of the forms I edit a model. The model has an image field `(public byte[] BioPhoto)`

When I upload an image to that field and save data, `ModelState.IsValid` is `false`, because `BioPhoto` property is `null` in ModelState. Note that the BioPhoto in model is loaded with image data.

I tried to inject the picture to ModelState using below code but still `ModelState.IsValid` is `false`

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "BusinessId,Name,About,Phone,TollFree,FAX,Email,Bio,BioPhoto")] Business business)
{
    if (System.IO.File.Exists("image.jpg"))
    {
        business.BioPhoto = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("image.jpg");
        ModelState.SetModelValue("BioPhoto", 
                   new ValueProviderResult(business.BioPhoto, "", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(business).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(business);
}
```

What am I doing wrong. Is there any better solution for this issue?

I read couple of answer in SO but could not figure out how to solve my case.

This is my model

```
public class Business
{
    public int BusinessId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Address address { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string TollFree { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string FAX { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string WebSite { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string About { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Bio { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public byte[] BioPhoto { get; set; }
}
```

My View

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BioPhoto, "BIO Photo (Best Size: 350 x 450)", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group" style="width:400px">
                <input id="BioPhoto" type="file" multiple class="file" data-overwrite-initial="false" />
            </div>
        </form>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BioPhoto, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show the class with all its validation attributes.

Comment: I added the model

Comment: And how are you uploading the image in the model from client side

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap FileInput. I add me view

Comment: Why do you have it marked `Required` if it is not required?

Comment: It is required. I did not say it's not required.

Comment: if its required then why is the controller not receiving it in the post?

Comment: That is the problem. and tha's why I tried to use SetModelValue but looks like it is not working

Comment: yes but what you are doing is hacking it. Find the reason why that is null. Did you try and see what the post body contains using chrome debugger?

Comment: @FLICKER check out this article. it shows how to use a custom byte array model binder that should fit your problem http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/6/model_binding_posted_file_to_byte_array

Comment: Try adding name attribute to the html tag, see if that makes a difference. Set the name attribute to the same value as the model property name.

Comment: Did you try `ModelState.Clear()` before revalidating the model? But the proper solution is to use `HttpPostedFileBase` as others suggested

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like I said the issue is the form is not posting the `BioPhoto` to the controller-most likely. You can use Chrome to see what is in the body of the http request.

If you want to add the image even if the controller is not receiving it, then try this.

Try removing only the error related to the image property:

```
ModelState["BioPhoto"].Errors.Clear();
```

Then add the image:

```
business.BioPhoto = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("image.jpg");
```

Then update the model:

```
UpdateModel(business);
```

Now if you call `ModelState.IsValid`, it will take the setting of `BioPhoto` into consideration and re-evaluate the `IsValid`.

EDIT:

I suggest to call

```
ModelState.SetModelValue("BioPhoto", new ValueProviderResult(business.BioPhoto, "", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

to actually push the value to ModelState.Values. this is not neccessary though.

Comment: I go with this answer as it's much easier than the other. Thank @Shyju anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using a view model, you should use a parameter of type `HttpPostedFileBase` for the image. Then in your action method, you can [convert it's InputStream property value to byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852102/convert-httppostedfilebase-to-byte) and save it.

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "BusinessId,Name,About,Phone,TollFree,
                    FAX,Email,Bio")] Business business,HttpPostedFileBase BioPhoto)
{
   // to do read BioPhoto.InputStream and convert to your byteArray
   // to do  :Return something
}
```

You have to remove the `[Required]` attribute from your byte array property of your model class.

The best solution is to use a view model which has only properties you needed from your view. You do not need to repost the image from the edit screen everytime. Update that property only if user selects a new image in the edit  form. If not do not update the existing value of that column when you save.

```
public class EditBusinessVm
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Address address { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public HttpPostedFileBase BioPhoto { set;get;}

    // Add other properties as needed.
}
```

Now your view must be strongly typed to this class

```
@model EditBusinessVm
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.Name)
  <input type="file" name="BioPhoto" />
  @Html.HiddenFor(f=>f.Id)
  <!-- add other fields needed -->
  <input type="submit"  />
}
```

and your httppost action method will use this type as parameter

```
public ACtionResult Edit(EditBusinessVm model)
{
  // purposefully omitting null checks/model validations code here

   //get existing entity
   var b=db.Businesses.FirstOrDefault(f=>f.BusinessId==model.Id);
  //update the properties from the posted view model
   b.Name = model.Name;
   if(model.BioPhoto!=null)  // user selected a new photo.
     b.BioPhoto = GetByteArray(model.BioPhoto);
   // to do : Set other properties as well.

   db.Entry(business).State = EntityState.Modified;
   db.SaveChanges();
   return RedirectToAction("Index");

}
private byte[] GetByteArray(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
   MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream();
   file.InputStream.CopyTo(target);
   return target.ToArray();      
}
```

Comment: The OP just said that this is required so the issue is elsewhere.

Comment: I bet the data for the byte array  field is not being posted from the form, hence the model validation is failing. He should not be loading and posting the **byte array** data from the form. He should post an HttpPostedFileBase instance if needed.

Comment: Removing required attribute works as a final alternative. I'm still trying to see why SetModelValue is not working. Thanks for your answer anyway. I'll mark it when I'm done with my research.

Comment: @Shyju, Are you saying I use HttpPostedFileBase  instead of byte[] ?

Comment: you can use `byte[]` for your entity model, but use `HttpPostedFileBase` for receiving an uploaded file data unless you have a custom model binder to do the transformation

Comment: I'm looking at ModelState.Values.Items[8].Value.RawValue and I see it contains data. So I'm wondering why ModelState.IsValid says "BioPhoto field is required".

Comment: @FLICKER the error message was already added by the framework so that is why it remains false even after you add the required field.

Comment: @Nkosi That's a good point. Is there any easy way to resolve this? otherwise I prefer to remove the Required attribute as suggested.

Comment: @FLICKER, I'm thinking you remove that error state which probably will remove the error and then add new state

Comment: @Shyju yes definitely the data is not being posted back. That is where the issue is.