# .NET5 - @HiddenFor(model => model.RowVersion) caches value?

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency

In my CRUD projects for **.NET5**, I use models with the RowVersion property of type byte [] that preserve the version of the row in order to detect a concurrency conflict.

If a DbUpdateConcurrencyException occurs while saving the model, I call a handler that obtains the stored model values ​​to populate the ModelState property and transfers the stored RowVersion value to the viewmodel. Then the view is displayed again with the original client values, with the values ​​stored in the validators if they differ from the client values, and with a concurrency conflict error message, as described in the concurrency conflict tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application#modify-department-controller

**Unfortunately**, if I use the HiddenFor method in the view, I get the original value of RowVersion, so the DbUpdateConcurrencyException occurs repeatedly when trying to save values ​​repeatedly, even though there is no concurrency conflict and the user insists on the specified values.

However, if I replace the call to the HiddenFor method with the manually entered input type = 'hidden', everything works as it should.

**This does not work** (value is still the same, not the value read from the stored data):

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.RowVersion)
```

**This works** (after concurrency conflict treatment, the value is read from the stored data):

```
<input type='hidden' name='RowVersion' value='@System.Convert.ToBase64String(Model.RowVersion)' />
```

This is the only change to fix the incorrect behavior. Does anyone have an explanation?

P.S.:
In the .NET Framework 4.7.2, this works correctly (both solutions work the same).

**Edit:**
Concurrency conflict handling method:

```
        protected virtual async Task<IActionResult> ConcurencyConflictHandleMethod(
            DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex,
            Controller controller,
            TViewModel viewModel,
            params object[] keyValues)
        {
            var entry = ex.Entries.Single();
            var clientValues = (TModel)entry.Entity;
            var databaseEntry = entry.GetDatabaseValues();
            if (databaseEntry == null)
            {
                var message = _localizer[NoDataPattern, keyValues];
                return _resultProvider.NoData(controller, message, ErrorSeverity.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                var savedValues = (TModel)databaseEntry.ToObject();
                await ConcurencyConflicts(controller.ModelState, clientValues, savedValues);

                controller.ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, _localizer[UpdateConcurrencyConflict]);

                var rowVersion = await _dalServices.SynchronizeCurrent(clientValues);
                _modelUpdater.SetRowVersion(viewModel, rowVersion);
                return await _detailsService.View(controller, _viewName, viewModel);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Compares client model values ​​with stored values 
        /// ​​and writes inconsistencies to the ModelState dictionary.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="modelState">
        /// Model state dictionary
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="clientValues">
        /// Client values
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="savedValues">
        /// Saved values
        /// </param>
        /// <returns>
        /// Task
        /// </returns>
        protected abstract Task ConcurencyConflicts(ModelStateDictionary modelState, TModel clientValues, TModel savedValues);
```

_dalServices contains an injected service which method SynchronizeCurrent returns saved value of RowVersion. Here is its default implementation:

```
        public virtual Task<byte[]> SynchronizeCurrent(TModel model)
        {
            var rowVersionName = _modelUpdater.RowVersionName;  // Gets the name of the column for row version from the service.
            var retVal = (byte[])_context.Entry(model).GetDatabaseValues()[rowVersionName]; // Gets the saved value of the row version.
            return Task.FromResult(retVal);
        }
```

SetRowVersion() is method of another injected service which sets the row version value of model or viewmodel. Here is its default implementation (GetModelPropertyName virtual method converts viewmodel property name to corresponding model property name and in default, it returns its parameter):

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Sets row version of modelu or viewmodel to given value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="model">
        /// Instance of model or viewmodel
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="rowVersion">
        /// Row version value
        /// </param>
        public void SetRowVersion(object target, byte[] rowVersion)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(RowVersionName))
                return;

            string targetRwPropName;        // The name of row version property in the target object
            if (target is TModel)
            {
                targetRwPropName = GetModelPropertyName(RowVersionName);
            } else
            {
                targetRwPropName = RowVersionName;
            }

            PropertyInfo pi = target.GetType().GetProperty(targetRwPropName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase);
            if (pi != null && pi.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(rowVersion.GetType()))
            {
                pi.SetValue(target, rowVersion);
            }
        }
```

Comment: `​​to populate the ModelState property` - how do you do that?

Comment: I'm going to add this information.

Comment: You don't seem to be [updating the model state](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41318349/11683).

Comment: I see that I will have to improve this: Instead of the GetDatabaseValues ​​method, I should call its asychronous version of GetDatabaseValuesAsync and I should not call it twice, instead I should use the read values.

Comment: Thank you, GSerg.

Comment: Thank you, with this command, it works: `controller.ModelState.SetModelValue(_modelUpdater.RowVersionName, new ValueProviderResult(Convert.ToBase64String(rowVersion)));'