# asp.net mvc fileupload ReadTimeout in HttpPostedFileBase inputstream

Tags: asp.net-mvc, upload, inputstream

I have action in asp.net mvc that accepts a uploaded file. The HttpPostedFileBase I get is not null and even ContentLength has value greater than 0, but when I inspect "InputSream", it has following error :

> ReadTimeout = '((System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper)refile).InputStream.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

So when I want to convert to readitbytes as follow, the there is nothing except empty array :

```
using (var reader = new System.IO.BinaryReader(refile.InputStream))
                    {
                        var a = reader.ReadBytes(model.File.ContentLength);
                    }
```

So "a" get "{byte[0]}".

What is the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

You might be missing `enctype` in you form. Please correct your form if there is such kind of issue. A MVC Form with files will be like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Advertisement", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    //Content
}
```

Thanks Hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

Abp is trying to validate MVC Action parameters and when it tries to read the value of your files parameter to validate it, this exception occurs.

You can ignore `HttpPostedFileWrapper` types for validation and everything should work perfectly.

Use this to get byte array from it (more details in : [Convert HttpPostedFileBase to byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852102/convert-httppostedfilebase-to-byte))

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
     refile.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
     byte[] a = ms.ToArray();

  }
```