# How to add pdf file to my existing database using Code First Migrations?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, file-upload, ef-code-first

[image: This is my rent model in which I have declared byte File in it]

[image: This is the database of my rent table in which File needs to be populated with pdf file path]

[image: This is my viewModel as I'm using code first for uploading fie]

[image: This is my post method]

Please tell me what to code here in order to get the file path only directly to the database table and please tell me how the view will look. Please help I'm stuck with this problem since 2 days.

Comment: asuming you're using EF for regular .NET (not netcore) seeding is what you're looking for https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-3

Comment: `HttpPostedFileBase` should only be used on your presentation layer (view model). In your enity class you should use `byte[]` or a path to the file

Comment: Yes, I'm using regular EF and I know how to populate the database table , but I want to know how to upload pdf file in my existing database and the moment file gets uploaded I want the file path to get populated in the FILE coloumn of my table @r1verside

Comment: I have shared the images , httppostedfilebase is used in viewmodel only . @CodeNotFound

Comment: So convert your [HttpPostedFileBase in byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7852256/797882) and set it to the correct property in your entity.